# Not able to connect espn developers account for access key

Tags: api, espn

I am trying to access http://developer.espn.com/member/register site for ESPN API key generation. But I think it is blocked and redirecting to documentations page.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

it is not working anymore, they have discontinued their public API,
for more information, please check this link:
http://espn.go.com/static/apis/devcenter/blog/read/publicretirement.html